# String matching with multiple prefixes

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

This is an algorithmic question; any pseudocode/verbal explanation will do (although a Python solution outline would be ideal).

Let's  have a query word `A`, for example `pity`. And let's have a set of other strings, `B`s, each of which is composed of one or more space-delimited words: `pious teddy`, `piston tank yard`, `pesky industrial strength tylenol`, `oh pity is me!` etc.

The goal is to **identify those strings `B` from which `A` could be constructed**. Here "constructed" means we could **take prefixes of one or more words in `B`, in order, and concatenate them together to get `A`**.

Example:

- pity = **pi**ston **t**ank **y**ard
- pity = **p**esky **i**ndustrial strength **ty**lenol
- pity = oh **pity** is me!

On the other hand, `pious teddy` should not be identified, because there's no way we can take prefixes of the words `pious` and `teddy` and concatenate them into `pity`.

The checking should be fast (ideally some regexp), because the set of strings B is potentially large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern of `\bp(?:i|\w*(?>\h+\w+)*?\h+i)(?:t|\w*(?>\h+\w+)*?\h+t)(?:y|\w*(?>\h+\w+)*?\h+y)` to match those words. It assumes spaces to be used as word separators. This is rather easy to construct, just take the first letter of your word to be matched, then loop over the others and construct `(?:[letter]|\w*(?>\h+\w+)*?\h+[letter])` from them.

This pattern is basically an unrolled version of `\bp(?:i|.*?\bi)(?:t|.*?\bt)(?:y|.*?\by)`, which matters the second to last letters either as exactly next letter or first letter (because of the word boundary) of a next word.

You can see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/r3ZVNE/2

I have added the last sample as non-matching one for some tests I did with atomic groups.

In Delphi I would do it like this:

```pascal
program ProjectTest;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  RegularExpressions;

procedure CheckSpecialMatches(const Matchword: string; const CheckList: array of string);
var
  I: Integer;
  Pat, C: string;
  RegEx: TRegEx;
begin
  assert(Matchword.Length > 0);
  Pat := '\b' + Matchword[1];
  for I := Low(Matchword) + 1 to High(Matchword) do
    Pat := Pat + Format('(?:%0:s|\w*(?>\h+\w+)*?\h+%0:s)', [Matchword[I]]);
  RegEx := TRegEx.Create(Pat, [roCompiled, roIgnoreCase]);
  for C in CheckList do
    if Regex.IsMatch(C) then
      WriteLn(C);
end;

const
  CheckList: array[0..3] of string = (
    'pious teddy',
    'piston tank yard',
    'pesky industrial strength tylenol',
    'prison is ity');
  Matchword = 'pity';
begin
  CheckSpecialMatches(Matchword, CheckList);
  ReadLn;
end
```

.

Comment: Neat! What's the difference between the "unrolled" and non-unrolled version? `(?:i|\w*(?>\h+\w+)*?\h+i)` vs `(?:i|.*?\bi)`

Comment: @user124114 Basically the `(?>\h+\w+)*?` steps through words word-by-word, while `.*?` steps through character by character. It also allows a little less backtracking due to the atomic group.